# Understanding training steps and getting measures from caret object (k-fold cross-validation)

Tags: r, cross-validation

I am an R beginner and I am trying to perform some analysis and want to check that my understanding is right.

This is the code I ran

```
tc <- trainControl(method="cv", 
                              number=5,
                              savePredictions=TRUE,
                              summaryFunction=twoClassSummary,
                              classProbs=TRUE)
fit <- train(x=data[,1:9], y=data[,10], method="rf", metric="ROC", trControl=train_control, tuneLength=5)

p_model <- predict(fit, data)

cm <- confusionMatrix(p_model, fit$trainingData$.outcome, mode="everything")
```

My questions are:

a) is it correct what I am doing by not splitting the data into train and test, because k-fold cv is already doing that (by selecting 1/5 for 5 times for test and the rest for train)?

b) are my prediction measures correctly done e.g. for AUC-ROC, precision/recall curve (my understanding is that this is done on the best tuned parameters chosen automatically and shows how well did the fit perform on the test set for that specific fold)?

c) if b) is right, is it common for the prediction to be done on the same data as in the k-fold cv, or it should have been done on a different data split even before the cross validation (e.g. 80/20 split, and the 80% to be used for cv and the rest of 20% to be kept for prediction on the test)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A: the repeatedcv will look at the best mean metric per tuning step. In your case 5 steps. It will then fit all the training data at that tune to get a $finalmodel.

So this means for C: you should have another separate holdout set.

B: see A.